# Pushbot Android or IOS how to get a device to register for specific types of Messages

Tags: android, ios

I have a question about PushBots(https://pushbots.com/). Sofar I have a basic Pushbot service working and all devices get notfications when they are sent out from the server.

However I would like to create types of messages which some devices may recieve and some may not. For example if it was a news application then I would like some devices to be able to register for Sports and Weather updates and receive message only for those topics.

I tried using TAGS to clasify messages but this did not, as all devices receive all messages regardless if it is using a TAG or not.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you looked here: https://pushbots.com/developer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your app you need first to use the SDK to tag those devices before you are able to send messages to them.

Android Example:

```
    Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
    // tag the device with "tag"
     Pushbots.getInstance().tag(appContext, "tag", null);
```

iOS Example

```
// Tag the device with "tag"
[[Pushbots getInstance] tag:@"tag"];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me ? So yes when I use tags in the application: Pushbots.getInstance().tag(getApplicationContext(), "EU", null); I put it in the Activity. On the Dashboard I can see that it was successful because for that device the TAG was updated. And I can send messages out using that TAG. However when I send a message that does not have a TAG that device also gets it aswel. Is this correct ?

Comment: If you send a message without a tag it will reach to everyone, but if you specify a tag it will be delivered to those who have this specificc tag. example if you have devices tagged with "sports" if you push a message without specifying a tag everyone will get it but if you want it to reach only people with sports tag you need to push with this tag.

However, if you share more code and exact scenario I would be able to help.

Comment: one last thing, if you want to send messages to everyone except for those who have this tag you can use "except_tags" in the REST API
https://pushbots.com/developer/rest#g14

Comment: Hi, after some more investigation I will mark this as correct answer. So this is how I understand behaviour. If 2 different devices have regsitered with two different tags then you can distinguish between the devices based on the TAG. If you send a message without any TAG then all devices receive the message. Pushbots is great !